# Stop function in node.js with click in frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js

There's a loop that optimizes something in the backend, I want it to go on forever until I hit a stop button in the frontend.

My (simplified) code so far:
On a button press this function is called

```
function optimize() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/optimize',
        success: function (data) {
            updatePlot(data);
        },
    });
}
```

In the backend:

```
let optimizingFunction = {};

router.get('/optimize', function (req, res) {
    optimizeFunction(); //This goes on for a long time...
    res.send(optimizingFunction);
});

function optimizeFunction(){
    while(true){
        let betterFunction = {};
        //...
        optimizingFunction = betterFunction;
    }
}
```

So now how can I stop this function on another button press and get the current optimizingFunction value? - I tried:
On a stop-button click

```
function stop() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/stop'
    });
}
```

Backend:

```
router.get('/stop', function (req, res) {
    process.exit(1);
});
```

I noticed it actually executes the stop function but after it executed the first one...
What's an easy 'best practice' approach for problems like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are a lot of different ways to go about this.  The easiest based on your example is probably to use a setTimeout instead of a loop, and then have some kind of variable you test before deciding to reset the timeout.  Something like this (untested):

```
const app = express(); 

function process() {
  // do work
  if(app.enabled('continue work')) {
    setTimeout(process, 1000); // run every second.  Could set that to smaller intervals
  }
}

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
  app.enable('continue work');
  process();
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/stop', (req, res) => {
  app.disable('continue work');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Note, however, this is suboptimal and not very scalable.  A better solution would use some kind of work queue or database.  Also, you generally don't want to change applications state with GET requests, but use POST or PUT instead.

Adding a more conventional HTTP pattern for doing this kind of work here:

```
const app = express(); 
const currentState = {}; // this *really* should be in a database for any nontrivial application.

function process() {
  // do work to add properties & values to currentState
  if(app.enabled('continue work')) {
    setTimeout(process, 1000); // run every second.  Could set that to smaller intervals
  }
}

app.post('/start', (req, res) => {
  app.enable('continue work');
  process();
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/state', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ state: currentState, processing: app.get('continue work') });
});

app.post('/stop', (req, res) => {
  app.disable('continue work');
  res.send(currentState);
});
```

Note that a lot of folks don't like URLs as 'actions' (start, stop, etc), but that's mostly preference.  Check out articles on REST APIs to understand what that approach looks like, if you care.

Comment: work queue or db just for stopping a function?? Omg, I was hoping it could be done much simpler :( Not sure about a timeout, but thanks - I will try this for now! :)

Comment: @Cold_Class Well, it depends on what you're actually doing.  If you can do all your work in just one node process, this is good enough.  If you ever need to use multiple, it's not shared memory space so you have to bring in something else to keep track of state.

Comment: Oh I noticed the object returned to the frontend is not the current one...how can I send it everytime after I run the process() function?

Comment: You can’t, not with Ajax at least. HTTP is limited to one response per request.  If you need to send information originating non the server look into web sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the buzzword web sockets, I will look into it - but for now it would be enough just to get the newest state. So I would wait until the stop before I send a response like this? `if(!app.enabled('continue work')) res.send(optimizingFunction);`

Comment: I’m having a really hard time understanding your use case at this point.  Your initial description had nothing about sending a response to the client at all, so I assumed we were talking about some kind of processing on the server that stayed on the server.  Again, the better approach for what you’re describing would not be maintained in memory.  That said, sure, you could do it as you describe so long as the process function has access to the response object. More Node-ish would be to have process take a callback function that it calls when it’s done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164254/discussion-between-cold-class-and-paul).